# How to draw application functional diagrams?

Tags: uml, diagrams, purely-functional

I'm trying to find some good reads to clarify this but I'm unable to find it (or maybe I just don't know how to search this properly).

What I'm trying to find is, considering that you have an application that:

- interacts with a db;
- interacts with Mainframe;
- interacts with external providers;
- etc...

What is the best approach to draw a diagram that represents this in a functional view rather then in a more techinical view? What kind of books, articles, websites can help me to get a clearer understanding of which approach should I follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a [deployment diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram)

Answer (score 0):

Well,

First thing that you should ask yourself:

> Why I am drawing or want to draw  a diagram about this?

Maybe you answer is :

> To understand important/significiant communication between those elements.

Then we can say:

> Oh maybe sequence diagram may help...

Buy may be you answer is:

> Oh I am worry about topology of system components. How those things
>   will be deployed?

Then we can say that:

> Oh, may be deployment diagram will help you...Draw one.

So depends on "context"...

UML diagrams will not solve your problems. They help you to understand tricky and hard part of your system  and think about alternative solutions by visual modeling.

Modeling is not "self masturbating" activity.  It is like "group sex". You will get most benefit when you do with others...

So the main problem is not to draw which diagram... The main problem is:

> What kind of problem you have? With whom you wanto to find solution? What kind of benefit may you get from drawing a diagram?

For UML i definelty suggest Larman book: Applying UML and Patterns :[Check at amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062)

And lastly, if UML does not fit your purpose, be creative and pragmatic...Use textual desription or even create your "own" visual modeling :-) or do anthing which help you...